# Cannot open a video using opencv 3.1 and python 3.6

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to open a video using opencv 3.1 and python 3.6 using an Industrial camera "catchBest" . Its driver is installed and device is listed in device manager. But it is not opening using opencv.

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    cam = video.read()
    cv2.imshow("video", cam)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
video.release()    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried index from 0 to 9 but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import cv2
#you can run a loop from 0 to 100 to check which gives true, if you're unsure which number to use.
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(video.isOpened()) #this should return True if camera opens successfully.
while True:
    #first returned value of video.read() is boolean and second is frame so we have to use second.
    ret,cam = video.read() 
    cv2.imshow("video",cam)
   #you have to break from infinite loop to release the camera usage, here I'm using escape key to break you can choose any.
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Problem is not with the index number. Problem is opencv is not detecting the camera.